# What does Form.MainMenuStrip actually do?

Tags: .net, winforms

The Form.MainMenuStrip property "gets or sets the primary menu container for the form", according to the docs. But what does this mean, behaviour-wise? The only thing I have noticed is that a maximised MDI child form will get its icon added to the menu strip only if this property is set.

Comment: Just one reason is often enough for a thing to be made. MDI child needs a way to change main menu. It can do that with MainMenuStrip.